# Write cout value to text file

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

The for loop is to randomize 65 - 90 and using (char) to display them in alphabet A-Z.

I can have the display in alphabet A-Z in the console but I am not able to write them in text file.

```
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    cout << (char) (letter[i] + 'A' - 1) << " ";

cout << endl;

ofstream output;
output.open("output.txt");
output << (char)letter[i] + 'A' - 1 << endl;
output.close();
```

Comment: Ahem. The code for both situations should be same. It isn't. (Hint: parentheses matter)

Comment: (2nd Hint: the `for` line matters).

Comment: This code is in such a poor state I refuse to take a look. Please organize it and post again.

Answer (score 0):

Since *std::ofstream* inherits from the same type as `std::cout` is an instance of (*std::ostream*) their interfaces are the same, some methods are added to the *file-handling* stream but other than that they are interchangeable.

With the above said the only thing required from your part is that you are actually implementing the functionality **the same way** in both cases, currently: (by reading your snippets) you are not.

1. the *std::ofstream* example doesn't have any loop
2. the order of evaluation is different (since you don't use `()`) in the *std::ofstream* snippet

---

To make sure you use the same implementation no matter if you are writing to a file or *standard-output* you could wrap the code in a function, making it accept a reference to *std::ostream* as in the below snippet.

```
#include <iostream>                                                           
#include <fstream>
```

```
void                                                                          
do_whatever (std::ostream& output_stream)                                     
{                                                                             
  int letter[] = {                                                            
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,                                         
    15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26                                       
  };                                                                          

  for (int i =0; i < 26; ++i)                                                 
    output_stream << (char) (letter[i] + 'A' - 1) << " ";                     
}
```

```
int                                                                           
main (int argc, char *argv[])                                                 
{                                                                             
  std::ofstream file_stream;                                                  

  file_stream.open ("file.txt");                                              

  do_whatever (file_stream);                                                  
  do_whatever (std::cout);                                                    
}
```

Comment: i am lost...
so how to make them interchangeable ?

Comment: @user1526669 post has been edited and supplied with new information, your question has been answered.

Comment: I have tried the method you given, it give me ⁃⁚⁅⁑⁁⁏⁔⁓⁘⁄⁗⁊⁕⁐⁖⁌⁇⁍⁂⁉⁈⁆⁒⁙⁋⁎ in the text file

Comment: @user1526669 without modifications of the code above there is no way that the output would be what you describe.

Comment: output<<(char)(letter[i]+'A'-1)<<" "<<endl;
by adding endl;
it display the alphabet but my text file display the character in horizontal, without endl; the text file display garbage.

Comment: I assume you have some weird content in your array `letter` and therefor adding 'A' and subtracting 1 won't make sense, as said; the snippet here is correct and your original question has been answered. You should accept this post and if you another question create a new one specific about that problem.